# How do I create a loop in spark?

Tags: loops, apache-spark

Hi How do I perform the following in spark? I would like to create a table of weights based on date using the following loop. Please can you show me how to create the same table in spark?

```
import datetime

from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

Last_month = datetime.datetime.strptime(todays_date,'%Y-%m-%d').date() + relativedelta(months=-1)
Last_month = Last_month.replace(day=1)
Last_month = Last_month.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
Last_month_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(Last_month, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
print(Last_month)
print(todays_date)



def create_weights(Period):
    i=1
    DF = pd.DataFrame()
    while i <= 12:
        j = 1
        while j <= Period:
            ct = j - 11 - i
            nw_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(Last_month,'%Y-%m-%d').date() + relativedelta(months=ct)
            data = pd.DataFrame([[i, nw_date, j]], columns = ['period','mdate','weight'])
            j += 1
            DF = pd.concat([DF,data])
        i += 1
    return DF

weights = create_weights(12)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 144)
weights
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output, it is easy anyone can help you.

Comment: I've added some additional code, it should work in python now. There should be 3 columns period, mdate and weight. How do you get it to work in spark?